# How to migrate users and keep their IDs unchanged?

Tags: 7, users, migrations

I'm trying to use migrate_d2d, via the UI, to migrate a site from D6 to D7.  I need to preserve user UID's in the migration.  I'm finding the documentation confusing..

Given this in the UI...

[image: Screen shot of UI]

What do I need to do to import the users?

Comment: Can you clarify? Sounds like you managed to import the users but they have different user id's compare to D6, is this correct?

Comment: The import works but the UIDs are not the same. I don’t know what the setting in the UI should be to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution (see image)

1. Uncheck DNM in 'Option:...' row
2. Enter 1 as default value
3. Save
4. Edit again
5. A new row will appear for 'Existing user ID'
6. Select Source field, i.e uid.
7. Save

This works...

[image]